# How to fix relative child routes Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-router

AppRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
   { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }
];
```

HomeRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent, children: [
    {path: 'inner', loadChildren: './home-inner/home-
inner.module#HomeInnerModule'},
  ]}
];
```

HomeInnerRoutingModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeInnerComponent}
];
```

And link to simple github example https://github.com/NazarKalytiuk/lazyRoutingAngular
And you can try here: https://stackblitz.com/github/NazarKalytiuk/lazyRoutingAngular

Please click inner twice and look in console. Second time route will go to inner/(inner). And same with other routes.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `home.component.html` define an absolute path an not a relative path to your destination url

```
<a routerLink="/inner">Inner</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

From the docs [RouterLinks](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description):

> The first segment name can be prepended with /, ./, or ../:
>
> - If the first segment begins with /, the router will look up the route from the root of the app.
> - **If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router will instead look in the children of the current activated route.**
> - And if the first segment begins with ../, the router will go up one level.